# Access query not working?

Tags: ms-access

I remember using a query like this which worked for me before. But now its giving me a compile error.

I am trying to get only the first 3 characters of the second field.

```
select field1, left(field2, 3) from table1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What datatype is field2 and does LEFT throw an error when the field has fewer than three characters in it?

Comment: its text type though it has numbers

Comment: What does the compile error say, exactly?

Comment: compile error. in query expression Left([field2], 3)

Comment: From memory LEFT is a VB function not an inherent SQL function - how/where are you making the SQL call?

Comment: @Murph: LEFT is a Jet-SQL function (for Access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your SQL statement.  Brackets around field name, semicolon at end of statement, fewer than 3 characters in `field2` --- those are all non-issues here.

There is something wrong with your database or your machine and/or its Access installation.  Ordinarily I would suspect a references problem because your error is a classic symptom.  However, in a comment, you indicated references are OK.

Create a new empty database and import `table1` into it.  Try your query in the new database.  If it works there, you know the problem is limited to the original database.  If the query does not work in the new database, copy the database to another machine which has Access installed and try it there.  If it works on another machine, but not yours, ... I hope there is some way to repair your original machine without re-installing Office.

Comment: something was wrong in the old database. it works in a new database.

Answer (score 3):

See this link:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/questions/compile_error.php

It says you can get a compile error when using Left() if you have a broken reference.  It also says how to fix it.

Comment: hmm but i dont seem to be missing any references

Answer (score 1):

What happens in Access if you hit Ctrl-G on the keyboard and in the immediate window type "?Left("123Text", 3)" and hit ENTER? If you get the same compile error, then you have either a missing reference, or a compile error in your database.

To troubleshoot this, while in the VBE window, go to the DEBUG menu and select the first choice, COMPILE [project name]. You will likely receive notification of a compile error, and it should direct you to the problem that you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the field name in square brackets

```
select field1, Left([field2], 3) from table1;
```

Comment: same its still giving compile error. in query expression Left([field2], 3)
What i dont understand is it was working fine earlier

Comment: If it was working before, check your database connections and table structure to make sure everything is still intact.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your SQL as long as your table names and column names are correct. Depending on your SQL editor or code, you may need to remove the semi colon from the statement.

Comment: If the table/column's weren't correct they'd get a different error e.g. 'No value given for one or more required parameters.' My money's on broken references.