# Peculiar Access 2007 issue, reports not displaying some fields

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-office, windows-10, office-2007, office-2013

Our office is having a very strange issue with Access 2007.

Long story short - over the past few weeks, half the computers were upgraded to Windows 10, and all of them were upgraded to Office 2013 - except for Access, which we kept at 2007 to keep legacy databases working a little while longer.

All the computers in the office are working perfectly fine under this setup.

Two of them, however, are not displaying some of the Access reports properly. Fields that are not directly linked to a table field and generated on the fly (for example, ControlSource property of the text field something like '=[ThisField] + " and " + [ThatField]') do not show up, and instead display "#Name?" as if it can't connect to the data. However, on the exact same report, there will be fields with the control source directly linked to a field (for example, "MyField" in the query in the report's record source) that will work just fine!

Only two computers in our office are having this problem; the rest display all fields as expected.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening? Is it some weird side effect of having Office 2013 and Access 2007 side by side? We do not have Access 2013 installed. It might be worth mentioning that these two computers were purchased around the same time; however, so were two others that are working fine, one of which is on Windows 10 and the other on 7.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On the affected computers, check for compile errors and reference problems. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1421531/3820271

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was checked for compile errors last week and didn't find any, but will double check.

Comment: OK, I've narrowed down part of the problem...it doesn't like that we are using the Chr() function to create line breaks in the text field. When I take out the Chr()'s, the field fills in.  In fact, on the computer having the issue, I can't even insert them back in - Access pops up an error about trying to insert an aggregrate function.  It seems like some library or something is missing on these two computers since the upgrades.  I tried repairing the 2007 Office install but this didn't do anything.

Comment: System functions like `Chr()` not working is a typical sign of missing/broken references. Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes and I double checked the reference list on my computer vs. her computer and they were exactly the same. Will have to look through the link again to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Looked again at that link, and did some more googling for Chr() not working, decided to play around with the reference list as one of the sites suggested, think it was this one: http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/AccessReferenceErrors.html . Unchecked and rechecked a few references, recompiled, now all is working. Quite strange... Thanks!